# Stack, Queue, Tree?

Tags: data-structures

`13,5,2,9,8` and `1` are inserted into data structure in that order.

An item is deleted using only a basic data structure operation. If the deleted item is `1`, the data structure cannot be?

1. Priority queue
2. Stack
3. Queue
4. Search tree

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I do not want to do your homework either.

Comment: @dfeuer Excuse me.. This is not homework question. It was question of book and my answer was also queue but giving answer was stack. That's why I asked this question. And also I already commented about why I put such question here but somebody removed it. Some problems may be very easy for you but might be confusing for beginners.

Comment: I see now that you are new here. I would suggest that you look around at the sorts of questions that tend to be well received and the sorts that tend not to be. One key is to give some indication of your own involvement in the problem—either what you've done to solve it or how it arose from another problem you were trying to solve.

Comment: @dfeuer okay. I will keep it in my mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It cannot be a queue, because a queue only supports "popping" the *oldest* item (FIFO: first in first out), and `1` is inserted *last*.